# Rails: Why does view page show the ActiveRecord Hashes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have two models CategoryFolder and Categories. CategoryFolder has many Categories, and Category belongs to CategoryFolder with foreign_id "parent_id"

For some reason, **when I try to loop through the folders and list the categories within them, the view page displays the record hashes, and I don't know how to get rid of it:**

[image]

Categories Controller

```
def index 
  @folders = current_account.category_folders.order("created_at ASC")
  @categories = current_account.categories.where(parent_id: nil).order("created_at ASC")
  # authorize! :read, Category
  render :layout => "admin"
 end
```

Categories View#index

```
      <% @folders.each do |folder| %>
        <%= folder.categories.order("title ASC").each do |category| %>
          <%= render partial: 'table_list', locals: { category: category } %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

---

The Folders-Categories relationship has been causing a few errors lately, and I'm not sure whether the relations are set up weirdly. For example, **even when I delete a category, the category title will still show under something like "@folder.categories.each ~ link_to title"** and when I click the title it gives me an error page.

Category.rb

```
 belongs_to :folder, class_name: "CategoryFolder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

CategoryFolder.rb

```
has_many :categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <% @folders.each do |folder| %>
    <%= folder.categories.order("title ASC").each do |category| %>
      <%= render partial: 'table_list', locals: { category: category } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Your loop should not have an equal sign, that equal prints out the loop results.

```
  <% @folders.each do |folder| %>
    <% folder.categories.order("title ASC").each do |category| %>
      <%= render partial: 'table_list', locals: { category: category } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The second line should have no sign